# How to Find current user in shellcommand?

Tags: shell, command

When running command prompt in Standard user account `echo %userprofile%` command shows current user name but when run as administrator it will shows admin user name.

How can i get current standard user name even the command prompt in run as administrator mode? What ShellCommand is used for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

```
for /f "tokens=2" %u in ('query session ^| findstr /R "^>"') do @echo %u
```

It works.